# Extraction information from PDF files using ML (Invoice number, line items in table)

Tags: machine-learning, python, named-entity-recognition

First of all, I am fairly new to the ML world. I have researched quite a lot on the different use cases that ML have, both in regards to working with text and images.

I am trying to build a "pipeline", that can extract a few data points from various supplier **invoices**:

1. Invoice number
2. Line items (that resides in tables)

   1. For each line item, I would need: **quantity** and **line amount**

​

My first thought was to just use a classic OCR parsing tool such as DocParser (which is basically a template-based OCR parsing tool, where you can create parsing rules for each different type of invoice layout). However, I took a look at my suppliers, and I have a lot of different layouts (with new ones being added regularly).

**I was thinking if ML can be used to accomplish this task?**

My idea for a pipeline:

1. All supplier invoices are converted from PDF to an image file (.jpg) and then resized so all have the same width and height.
2. Train a custom model to extract invoice number using **named entity recognization (NER)**
3. Train a custom *computer vision* model to identify tables that contain line items (product information)

   1. For each table found, extract that as an image and train another model to identify the entities that I need for each line: **quantity** and **line amount**

I am not sure if this is a good approach to this problem? Does it make sense to ultimately end off with **three** models to extract the information that I need? Is there an easier way to detect the **quantity** and **line amount,** than by first locating the table on the PDF file?

Does anyone have any experience with a similar process?

Comment: If the number of different invoices styles is not overwhelmingly large, I would go with writing custom script for each invoice type. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract does a decently good job at extracting data from images provided they are not hand written.